# If value is present in stored text string

Tags: mysql

I have a table, one of the columns contains a text values, some of which are comma separated string, like this:

```
Downtown, Market District, Warehouse District
```

I need to modify my query to see is a given value matches this column. I decided that using IN() is the best choice.

```
SELECT * 
FROM t1
WHERE myValue IN (t1.nighborhood)
```

I am getting spotty results - sometimes I return records and sometimes not. If there's a value in **t1.nighborhood** that matches **myValue**, I do get data.

I checked and there are no MySQL errors. What am I missing?

Comment: *If there's a value in t1.nighborhood that matches myValue, I do get data.* Isn't that what you want? When doesn't it work?

Comment: It doesn't work when the myvalue =  Downtown and t1.nighborhood = Downtown, Market District, Warehouse District. However it DOES work when t1.nighborhood = Downtown

Comment: That makes sense. See my answer.

Comment: See my answer to [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad/3653574#3653574)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `FIND_IN_SET()` to search a comma-delimited list:

```
SELECT * 
FROM t1
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(myValue, REPLACE(t1.nighborhood, ', ', ','));
```

The `REPLACE()` is necessary to remove the extra spaces.

Another solution is to use regex to match your search value surrounded by commas if necessary:

```
SELECT * 
FROM t1
WHERE t1.nighborhood REGEXP CONCAT('(^|, )', myValue, '(, |$)');
```

In general, it's bad design to store distinct values in a single column. The data should be normalized into a related table with a foreign key.

Comment: Unfortunately still the same outcome. Here's my query: SELECT gb_restaurants.*, business_profile.busID, business_profile.busOnline, gb_restaurant_bounty.* FROM gb_restaurants LEFT JOIN business_profile ON (business_profile.yelpAPIid = gb_restaurants.yelpAPIid) LEFT JOIN gb_restaurant_bounty ON (gb_restaurant_bounty.bounty_busID = gb_restaurants.id) WHERE gb_restaurants.busState = 'TX' AND restaurants.busCity = 'Austin' AND FIND_IN_SET('Arboretum', REPLACE('restaurants.neighborhood', ', ', ',')) ORDER BY business_profile.busOnline DESC, business_profile.busID DESC

Comment: @santa `restaurants.neighborhood` is a column name; it shouldn't be in quotes.

Comment: That was it! Thanks.